# How do I create two different comboboxes with different strings of items?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I have created a combo box having a list of items. How do I create another one with different strings of items? Can I in anyway change the hWnd because it seems the first already has the hWndCombobxes. Thus, when I apply it to the second, I get an error message, indicating that there is a duplicate value. 
Below is the code I have. What function should I call else?

```
case WM_CREATE: {

        HWND hWndComboBox =    CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
               CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                100, 150, 200, 150,
                hwnd ,(HMENU) ID_COMBOBOX 1, NULL, NULL);

        //  ADD 2 ITEMS
        SendMessage  (
            hWndComboBox,
            (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
            (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 1"));

        SendMessage  (
            hWndComboBox ,
            (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
            (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM)  TEXT ("Item 2"));

        //  SEND THE CB_SETCURSEL MESSAGE TO DISPLAY AN INITIAL ITEM IN SELECTION FIELD
        SendMessage (hWndComboBox , LB_SETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 1);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaingful. C# and combobox are both in your tags, which means the only relevant word is *combobox*, which has zero informational content. Your title should describe the problem you're having or the specific question you're asking, in a way that will have meaning to a future user who finds it in a search result. It's unnecessary in almost every case to simply repeat information you're able to provide in the tags. Thanks.

Comment: Also, C# is nowhere near C (which is nowhere near being C++). Please use tags that are actually relevant to your question, instead of just using random ones that seem similar or sound familiar. This in no way is C# code, and therefore the tag is wrongly applied. Tags here are very relevant and have specific meaning; please read the descriptive text that appears when you try to use them, and only use the ones that are actually applicable to your question. If you're not sure, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// put this declaration somewhere up (or better move it to an include file)
#define ID_COMBOBOX_1     1001   
#define ID_COMBOBOX_2     1002
// end defines

case WM_CREATE: {


    // it is preferably to use SendDlgItemMessage instead of SendMessage
    // this make things easier
    // you will not need combobox's HWND, just ComboBox ID

    TCHAR *Combo_1_Data[]={
        TEXT("Item 1"),
        TEXT("Item 2")
    };

    TCHAR *Combo_2_Data[]={
        TEXT("Element 1"),
        TEXT("Element 2")
    };


    int i;

    // create two different ComboBoxs
    CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
        CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
        100, 150, 200, 150,
        hwnd ,(HMENU) ID_COMBOBOX_1, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
        CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
        208, 150, 200, 150,
        hwnd ,(HMENU) ID_COMBOBOX_2, NULL, NULL);


    // Fill first Combo with its Data
    for( i = 0 ; i < (sizeof(Combo_1_Data) / sizeof(Combo_1_Data[0]) ) ; i++ ){

        SendDlgItemMessage  (hwnd,ID_COMBOBOX_1 ,CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) Combo_1_Data[i]);
    }
    SendDlgItemMessage (hwnd, ID_COMBOBOX_1  , LB_SETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 1);


   // Fill second Combo with its Data
    for( i = 0 ; i < (sizeof(Combo_2_Data) / sizeof(Combo_2_Data[0] )) ; i++ ){

        SendDlgItemMessage  (hwnd,ID_COMBOBOX_2 ,CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) Combo_2_Data[i]);
    }
    SendDlgItemMessage (hwnd, ID_COMBOBOX_2  , LB_SETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 1);
```

Comment: there is an error message claiming 'scalar object 'Combo_1_Data' requires one element in initializer' and then same thing for 'Combo_2_Data'. Moreover, am told 'ID_COMBOBOX_1' was not declared and when I define them, I get bunch of error messages. What should I do please. Thanks though for answering.

Comment: the error `scalar object` was thrown because i forget to add accolades `[]` to the arrays  `Combo_1_Data` and `Combo_2_Data`

Comment: sorry for not replying earlier though, I was checking to see if everything is as it is. I have an error message '' invalid operands of types 'unsigned int' and 'TCHAR' {aka char}' to binary 'operator/'

Comment: sorry, it should be `sizeof(Combo_2_Data) / sizeof(Combo_2_Data[0] )` instead of `sizeof(Combo_2_Data) / Combo_2_Data[0]` ,same thing for the first one Combo_1_Data ,  that was an error from me. i think i am getting tired

Comment: rather unfortunately, the application would not even build this time. A dialogue message comes indicating 'a problem has caused main.exe to stop working , Windows would notify you when there is a solution'. Any way forward?

Answer (score -2):

Copy and paste the other combobox. Do the same for the 'Send message' function. Then change the hWnd of the second Combobox to hWndListBox. Do the same to 'Send message'.

```
 HWND hWndListBox  = CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
                    CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD  ,
                    100, 70, 200, 90,
                    hwnd ,(HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

                 HWND hWndComboBox =    CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
                   CBS_DROPDOWN| CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL| WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                    100, 150, 200, 100,
                    hwnd ,(HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SendMessage  (
            hWndComboBox ,
            (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
            (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM)  TEXT ("Item 2"));


     SendMessage  (
            hWndListBox ,
            (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
            (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 1"));


    //  SEND THE CB_SETCURSEL MESSAGE TO DISPLAY AN INITIAL ITEM IN SELECTION FIELD


    SendMessage (hWndComboBox , CB_SETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
    SendMessage (hWndListBox    , CB_SETCURSEL , (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
```

Comment: please format your code http://i.stack.imgur.com/vCW2k.png - and remove the `c#` tag from your question